# How did Hardy and Littlewood formulate the k-tuple conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}_k = (h_1,h_2,\cdots,h_k)$ be an admissible k-tuple.

**The k-tuple conjecture** predicts that the number of primes $(b+h_1,b+h_2,\cdots,b+h_k)\in \mathbb{P}^k$ with $b+h_k \leq x$ is:

$$\pi_{\mathcal{H}_k}(x) \sim \left(\prod_{\text{p prime}}\frac{1-\frac{w(\mathcal{H}_k, p)}{p}}{(1-\frac1p)^{k}} \right)\dfrac{x}{\log(x)^k}$$

Where $w(\mathcal{H}_k, p)$ is the number of distinct residues $\pmod p$ in $\mathcal{H}_k$.

We can deduce this formula from **Cramer's random model**, but Hardy and Littlewood get the same result using the circle method.

How did Hardy and Littlewood formulate this conjecture using the circle method?

Comment: The question has been asked and answered on [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312988/first-hardy-littlewood-conjecture) and [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54223/whence-the-k-tuple-conjecture). Here is a link to [Some Problems of Partitio Numerorum III, On the Expression of a Number as a Sum of Primes, Acta Math. 44, 1-70, 1922](http://fuchs-braun.com/media/8cdd73c813c342f8ffff80d1fffffff0.pdf), where it is formulated.

Comment: @Conifold, this article about Goldbach conjecture and some other types of primes sets (not including k-tuple conjecture)

Comment: This is the reference that [Green and Tao, p.6](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606088) give. Perhaps, it is in other parts of Some Problems of Partitio Numerorum? They also mention Dickson's 1904 paper.

Comment: @Conifold, this article didn't use the circle method, and use a complex notations and methods..

Comment: You mean Green-Tao's? Or Hardy-Littlewood's? Did you look at parts I, II and IV?

Comment: The $k$-tuple conjecture *is* in the paper mentioned by Conifold.  You need to look through the whole paper, not just the first few pages. :) See Theorem X1 on page 61. It depends on Hypothesis X (unproved) on p. 56.

Comment: Thank you for yours answers